# Insertar datos y actualizar los datos a la vez con un botón

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy intentando realizar un botón que haga la función de actualizar y insertar a la vez, pero se me ha complicado, ya que usar los al mismo tipo no funcionan correctamente. Estoy usando JTable, pero primero hay que guardar para que se genere la ID y después actualizar la JTable para que aparezca todo bien hasta ahí, pero si el método Guardar se ejecuta primero y yo solo quiero modificar una Row de la JTable me produce un error, y si se ejecuta el Modificar primero y yo quiero guardar una nueva Row con información me daría error ya que el Modificar se ejecuta primero y no el método Guadar, espero me haya hecho entender, gracias de antemano.

Codigo para Guardar

```
   public void Save() {
       
       try {

           String SaveSQL = "INSERT INTO PrimeroA (`Cedula`, `Apellido y Nombre`) VALUES (?, ?)"
                   + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Cedula` = VALUES (`Cedula`)";

           Connection = ConnectionBD.getConnection();

           for (int row = 0; row < tblPrimerA.getRowCount(); row++) {
               for (int column = 0; column < tblPrimerA.getModel().getColumnCount(); column++) {
                   if (tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, column) != null) {

                       ps = Connection.prepareStatement(SaveSQL);

                       ps.setObject(1, tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 1));
                       ps.setObject(2, tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 2));

                       ps.executeUpdate();
                   }
               }
           }
           
           ps.executeUpdate("SET @count = 0");
           ps.executeUpdate("UPDATE PrimeroA SET ID = @count:= @count + 1");
           ps.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE PrimeroA AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");

           ps.close();
           Connection.close();

       } catch (SQLException e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha ocurrido un ERROR al intentar guardar los datos.", "Guardar", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       }
   }
```

Codigo para Actualizar

```
    public void UpdateDB() {

        try {

            String UpdateSQL = "UPDATE PrimeroA SET `Cedula` = ?, `Apellido y Nombre` = ? WHERE `ID` = ?";

            Connection = ConnectionBD.getConnection();

            for (int row = 0; row < tblPrimerA.getRowCount(); row++) {

                ps = Connection.prepareStatement(UpdateSQL);

                ps.setInt(3, (int) tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 0));
                ps.setObject(1, tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 1));
                ps.setObject(2, tblPrimerA.getValueAt(row, 2));

                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
            
            ps.close();
            Connection.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (e.getErrorCode() == 1062) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El número de cedula " + e.getMessage() + " ya está registrado.", "Guardar", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha ocurrido un ERROR al intentar actualizar los datos.", "Guardar", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Algunas bases de datos tienen el comando UPSERT o equivalente. Eso te podría simplificar la vida en estos casos.

Comment: Poner ALTER TABLE en tu codigo transaccional no parece correcto para nada. Mejor define tu DB para que los ids se generen con AUTOINCREMENT:

CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
     ... // otros campos
);

Comment: Muchas gracias, he podido solucionar la inconveniencia que tenia, estaba colocando mal el ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: El ALTER TABLER era para resetear el auto_increment del ID porque cuando elimino queda de la siguiente manera 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 72, 151, 121... Y cuando lo reseteaba se acomodaba nuevamente, que podría hacer en ese caso?

Comment: no deberias hacer alter table en transacciones.. esto es mala practica... no debe importarte el valor del ID tampoco. No es importante.